# GXP Hidden layer switcher - composer.html

Tags: openlayers-2, boundless-suite, wps, geoexplorer

I am working with GeoServer, GeoExplorer, GXP. I am creating a WPS client and need to generate a vector layer that serves to make operations on vector data, such as buffer, split polygon.  I know how to create the vector layer but I want that is not on the menu layers GeoExplorer, I want this hidden.

I try modify this script wpsdemo.js from (http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/processing/wpsclient/index.html ) where:

In wpsdemo.js replace:

```
....
target.on('ready', function() {
            // Get a reference to the vector layer from app.js
            this.layer = target.getLayerRecordFromMap({
                name: 'sketch',
                source: 'ol'
            }).getLayer();
            // Some defaults
....
```

for code that does the following:

1. create dynamically  OpenlayerLayer.Vector (with `name: ''sketch', source: 'ol', displayInLayerSwitcher: false`)  <---- I know how to do it
2. add this layer to the map   <---- I don't know (my map is defined in composer.html)
3. GIS operations do but with the hidden layer in the layers menu switch

I try the following settings (in the composer.html) using the property **displayInLayerSwitcher: false** but does not work :

```
{
   // A vector layer to display our geometries and processing results
   source: "ol",
   name: "Res",
   type: "OpenLayers.Layer.Vector",
   fixed: true,
   visibility: false,
   selected: false,
   displayInLayerSwitcher: false        
}
```

In what way I can hide the layer in the layer switcher of GeoExplorer?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the args config property instead so:

```
type: "OpenLayers.Layer.Vector",
args: [null, {displayInLayerSwitcher: false}]
```